# When my Speech recognition was done, it always changes into another activity

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

**It always changes into another activity when speech recognition is done
This is my code. What must be the problem?**

I can get the result from speech recog.when it is done but it automatically changes to CropActivity

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

            m_edtInputText.setText(result.get(0));
            m_mic.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            sttProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = getPickImageResultUri(data);
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .start(this);

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_in_right);


    }

    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CropActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imageUri", resultUri);
            startActivity(intent);

        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }

    if(requestCode == MY_CHECK_DATA){
        if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS){
            m_TTS = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent m_installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            m_installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(m_installTTSIntent);
        }
    }



    }
```

Comment: We don't know how you are firing the intent.

Comment: Is the request code might be the problem?

Comment: Yep, that is likely an issue with your code